# SPFx - Template for email with PnP Core Library

Tags: spfx, pnp-js-core

With SharePoint Framework I use PnP Core Library to [**send mail**](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-SP.Utilities.Utility) to another user:

```
import pnp, { EmailProperties } from "sp-pnp-js";

const emailProps: EmailProperties = {
    To: ["user@site.com"],
    CC: ["user2@site.com", "user3@site.com"],
    Subject: "This email is about...",
    Body: "Here is the body. <b>It supports html</b>", // i need load this in Centralized location[without hardcoded];
};

pnp.sp.utility.sendEmail(emailProps).then(_ => {

    console.log("Email Sent!");
});
```

I want use template for "Body" property because I have several cases for a different template, because this is different in comparison SP Workflows

How would I do it in the best way?
JSON in document library in current web?
HTML in document library in current web?

Comment: I think storing HTML in lists is a good idea. And there are good examples on GitHub to get items from List.

Comment: Thank you! Is this the best way to send an email with pnp-core-library in SPFx?

Comment: In my opinion easiest and simple way with good performance is the best way. I find storing & retrieving data in list very easy.